# Object not being passed into callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am using filterSeries of the async npm but when I call the truthy next on the object, for some reason it only passes the user and not the parts trying to be taken out of the query...

If you notice what is wrong with my code or have a more efficient way of going about this, because I also, heard that looping through each users and calling a query is a bad idea instead to do a $in or something but not sure how.

The main thing is I want to combine both documents and feed it back as data...

Here is the code:

```
exports.searchContactPost = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.searchContacts === '') { res.send('Oops you searching for nothing, well here is nothing!'); };
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            User.find({$or:[
                {firstName: req.body.searchContacts.toLowerCase()},
                {lastName: req.body.searchContacts.toLowerCase()},
                {email: req.body.searchContacts.toLowerCase()}]
            }, function(err, users) {
                if(err || users.length === 0) { res.send(err);}
                callback(null, users)

            });
        },
        function(users, callback) {
            async.filterSeries(users, function(user, next) {
                console.log(user);
                Friend.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid, friend_id: user}, function(err, friend) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("houston we got a problem.")
                    }
                    var object = {'fav': friend.favorites, 'notes': friend.notes, 'labels': friend.labels, 'user': user, 'status':friend.friend_status};
                    console.log(friend);
                    next(object.status === 3);
                })
            }, function(friendResults){
                console.log(friendResults);
                callback(null, friendResults);
            });
        }
    ],

    function(err, results) {
        res.render('contactListResults', {title: 'Weblio', friendsFound: results});
    }); 
};
```

Comment: As currently written, it's very difficult to understand your question and the specific issue you're having.

Comment: djbrick understood it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async filter function takes an array of items and filters out items from that array based on a true or false callback. Therefore you will get back a subset of the original array passed into the filter. Which in this case is users, I believe your trying to build up a friend object and return it, which won't work. What you should do instead is just query the database for all friends of the appropriate status instead of using a filter.